# Regex line to split an array of items accumulated in a file

Tags: java, regex

Here is my list of Items in a file

```
Name1
2019  8293
Name1
2019  8293
Name1
2019  8293
Name1
2019  8293
```

I want to parse through this and add the data to a data object. The fields I want are `String name, int year` and `int population`.

But let us say that I want to put this into an array first. I accumulate the string and then I want to split it like so `String[] array = output.split(regex);` and then the output I want is for the array to have the values `[name1, 2019, 8293 , ...]`

As far as the code is concerned, I have a plan on how I will handle that, but this file format is really messing me up.  Any help would be appreciated.

Note: 
I tried `"\r\n|\n|[  ]"`

Comment: Read the 1st line and the 2nd line of each group separately. Then split 2nd line on the space.  No regex required.

Comment: I spent too much time on this for a simple solution. Thank you. I think I got fixated on the fact that someone suggested using regex that I forgot to look at the problem from another perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example desired output, in particular the:

"and then the output I want is for the array to have the values `[name1, 2019, 8293 , ...]`"

You can do something like this:

```
String[] array = {}; // Array to hold the final readin in results
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // List inteferface for processing file data.
try {
    // Using for/each and java.nio.file to process file contents.
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Data_File.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        line = line.trim(); // Trim the line of leading or trailing whitespaces.
        // Skip Blank Lines (if any) in file...
        if (line.equals("")) {
            continue;
        }
        // If a file line consists of two numerical values consisting
        // of one or more digits separated by one or more whitespaces... 
        if (line.matches("\\d+\\s+\\d+")) {
            // Split the line into Year and Population then
            // add them to the list.
            list.add(line.split("\\s+")[0]);  // Year
            list.add(line.split("\\s+")[1]);  // Population
        }
        // Otherwise the line must be a Name.
        else {
            // Add Name to the list.
            list.add(line);                   // Name
        }
    }
    // Convert List to String[] Array
    array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}

// Display the results read in from file now contained within the array[] Array.
String arrayString = Arrays.toString(array);
// Remove Square Brackets ([]) for display.
System.out.println(arrayString.substring(1, arrayString.length() - 1));
```

The above code is well commented and should explain well enough in detail what is being done. If you require more assistance then please don't hesitate to ask.

> **Data_File.txt Contents:**

```
Name1
2019  9999
Name2
2019  8585
Name3
2019  8888
Name4
2018  7777
```

> **Console output after running the above code:**

```
Name1, 2019, 9999, Name2, 2019, 8585, Name3, 2019, 8888, Name4, 2018, 7777
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Reader dataReader = new FileReader("D:\\data.txt");
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(dataReader);
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] yearAndPopulation = new String[2];
                String name;
                if (line.indexOf(' ') < 0) {
                    name = line;
                    //Read next line;
                    if((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        //replace all duplicated spaces by single space
                        line = line.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
                        yearAndPopulation = line.split(" ");
                        result.add(new String[] {name, yearAndPopulation[0], yearAndPopulation[1]});
                    }
                }
            }
            printResult(result);
        } finally {
            dataReader.close();
            bufferReader.close();
        }

    }

    private static void printResult(List<String[]> result) {
        for (String[] arr : result) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Name:%s, Year:%s, Population:%s", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]));
        }
    }
}
```